# Is it possible to get the contents of a variable with read_text() in Python script?

Tags: python, bash, variables

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

hello="HELLO"
who="WORLD"
text="$hello $who"
```

test.py:

```
import pathlib

content = pathlib.Path('test.sh').read_text()
print(content)
```

I want to get "HELLO WORLD" in my script py

Comment: Do you expect to get `"$hello $who"` or `"HELLO WORLD"`?

Comment: I want "HELLO WORLD"

Comment: Is this `test.sh` script a requirement or an answer you came up with as to how to store variables? Do you want to also tell us the problem you're trying to solve? There can be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `echo $text` on your 'test.sh' file
and then capture the output of the file by using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['./test.sh'], capture_output=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, as `content` is a string variable:

```
import pathlib
import re

content = pathlib.Path('test.sh').read_text()
print(re.search('text="(.+?)"', content))
```

**Output:**

```
<re.Match object; span=(37, 55), match='text="$hello $who"'>
```

To get the exact `text` value, you can slice the string:

```
import pathlib
import re

content = pathlib.Path('test.sh').read_text()
v = re.search('text="(.+?)"', content)
print(v[0][6:-1])
```

Resulting in:

```
$hello $who
```

Comment: It is unclear if OP wants "$hello $who" or "HELLO WORLD"

Comment: @buran Well, I guess he wants the raw output to be manipulated after getting it.

Comment: That's my point - you are guessing. I, for example, guess he wants to evaluate the variable and get the "HELLO WORLD"